# Using sed to print and replace text in the output of the ps command

Tags: command-line, bash, tty, sed

1. How to print the tty column from ps via sed?

   ```
     PID      TTY        TIME CMD
   13445    pts/7    00:00:00 bash
   15286    pts/7    00:00:00 sort
   15336    pts/7    00:00:00 sort
   18896    pts/7    00:00:00 sed
   19387    pts/7    00:00:00 ps
   ```
2. How to replace the rows of TTY with 'terminal'?

Comment: what text do you actually want to replace?

Comment: Why via sed? Why not `ps -o tty`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### 1. How to print the tty column from `ps` with `sed`?

```
ps | sed 's/ *[^ ]* *\([^ ]*\).*/\1/'
```

#### Explanations

I'll use `␣` for the space character.

- `s/A/B/` – `s`ubstitute `A` by `B` one time per line
- `␣*` – 0 or more spaces
- `[^␣]*` – 0 or more characters that are *not* (`^`) a space
- `\(…\)` – a group, everything inside the escaped brackets gets saved as `\1` as it's the first group here
- `.*` – 0 or more occurences of any character except newline
- `\1` – calls the afore saved group

#### Alternative ways

```
ps -o tt
ps | awk '{print $2}'
```

---

### 2. How to replace the TTY row with “terminal”?

```
ps | sed '2,$s/\([^0-9 ][^ ]*\)/terminal/'
```

#### Explanations

- `2,$` – process every line from the second to the last (so leave the first line out) – I assumed you want the `TTY` heading to stay, if not just omit this.
- `[^0-9␣]` – any one character except one of these: `0123456789␣`
- `terminal` – the string `terminal`

#### Alternative way

```
ps | sed '2,$s/\([0-9 ]*\)[^ ]*/\1terminal/'
ps | awk '{$2="terminal";print}' # change every line
ps | awk '{if(NR>1){$2="terminal"};print}' # omit first line
```

Answer (score 7):

`ps` has lots of options - you shouldn't need to parse it to get the output you want (the same applies to many commands, but this is especially unhelpful with `ps` because the output you get will include the program parsing the output...)

If you really want to though, you can parse it to print the TTY column with `sed` like this:

```
$ ps | sed -r 's/^ +[^ ]+ +([^ ]+) .*/\1/'
TTY
pts/4
pts/4
pts/4
```

#### Notes

- `-r` use extended regex
- `s/old/new/` replace `old` with `new`
- `^` start of line
- `+` one or more of the preceding character
- `([^ ]+)` save some non-space characters later
- `.*` any number of any characters
- `\1` back-reference to the saved pattern

You can probably replace the pts text like this:

```
$ ps | sed 's:pts/\?[0-9]*:terminal:'
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 3379 terminal    00:00:00 bash
 3466 terminal    00:00:00 ps
 3467 terminal    00:00:00 sed
```

#### Notes

- `s:old:new:` replace `old` with `new`
- `\?` zero or one of the preceding character
- `[0-9]*` zero or more digits